# How do I know which topic this word comes in?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp

This code works fine but I want to know the topic name instead of Topic: 0 and Topic:1, How do i know which topic this word comes in?

```
for index, topic in lda_model.show_topics(formatted=False, num_words= 30):
        print('Topic: {} \nWords: {}'.format(idx, [w[0] for w in topic]))
```

## This is ouput

```
Topic: 0 
Words: ['associate', 'incident', 'time', 'task', 'pain', 'amcare', 'work', 'ppe', 'train', 'proper', 'report', 'standard', 'pmv', 'level', 'perform', 'wear', 'date', 'factor', 'overtime', 'location', 'area', 'yes', 'new', 'treatment', 'start', 'stretch', 'assign', 'condition', 'participate', 'environmental']
Topic: 1 
Words: ['work', 'associate', 'cage', 'aid', 'shift', 'leave', 'area', 'eye', 'incident', 'aider', 'hit', 'pit', 'manager', 'return', 'start', 'continue', 'pick', 'call', 'come', 'right', 'take', 'report', 'lead', 'break', 'paramedic', 'receive', 'get', 'inform', 'room', 'head']
```

## I want "Topic Name" instead of Topic : 0

```
Topic: 0 
Words: ['associate', 'incident', 'time', 'task', 'pain', 'amcare', 'work', 'ppe', 'train', 'proper', 'report', 'standard', 'pmv', 'level', 'perform', 'wear', 'date', 'factor', 'overtime', 'location', 'area', 'yes', 'new', 'treatment', 'start', 'stretch', 'assign', 'condition', 'participate', 'environmental']
Topic: 1 
Words: ['work', 'associate', 'cage', 'aid', 'shift', 'leave', 'area', 'eye', 'incident', 'aider', 'hit', 'pit', 'manager', 'return', 'start', 'continue', 'pick', 'call', 'come', 'right', 'take', 'report', 'lead', 'break', 'paramedic', 'receive', 'get', 'inform', 'room', 'head']
```

Comment: What is a Topic Name? Can you show one example?

Answer (score 0):

This might work (Untested)

```
for index, topic in lda_model.show_topics(formatted=False, num_words= 30):
        print('Topic: {} \nWords: {}'.format(lda_model.print_topic(index), [w[0] for w in topic]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Formatted parameter to `True` like this:

```
for index, topic in lda_model.show_topics(formatted=True, num_words= 30):
        print('Topic: {} \nWords: {}'.format(topic[0], [w[0] for w in topic[1]]))
```

You can also check out the documentation for more information:
https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html